# First-order Stochastic Dominance equivalence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

We know that the first-order stochastic dominance is defined as
$$
X_A \succsim^{FD}X_B \Leftrightarrow F_A(x)\le F_B(x)
$$
where $F$ is the CDF, defined as $F(x)\equiv \Pr(X \le x)$.

Now suppose I define $G(x)\equiv \Pr(X\ge x)$ for a random variable. Is the following statement true?
$$
X_A \succsim^{FD}X_B \Leftrightarrow G_A(x)\ge G_B(x)
$$
If not, what's the counter-example?

Of course, it is easy when $X_A,X_B$ are completely continuous distributions since $\Pr(X>x)=\Pr(X\ge x)$.

The problem that I'm confused with is what if the distributions are discrete or mass points exist.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this statement is equivalent. To prove it, you can use the fact that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and any random variable $Z$, we have as $n\rightarrow\infty$,

$$ \{Z> x-1/n\}\nearrow \{Z \geq x\} \implies P[Z>x-1/n] \nearrow P[Z\geq x].$$

---

Another useful equivalence is the *coupling result*  that $P[X>x] \leq P[Y>x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if there is a random variable $Z$ with the same distribution as $X$ and such that $Z \leq Y$.